# Header property in custom theme is not working

Tags: json, powerbi

I'm creating a sample theme for Power BI and trying to set the font color for header and it is not updating automatically after importing.

Is there any issue in my below sample. Can anyone please help?

Here is my sample JSON:

```
{  
   "visualStyles":{  
      "donutChart":{  
         "*":{  
            "legend":[  
               {  
                  "show":true,
                  "fontSize":"16",
                  "labelcolor":"#8aa5d1"
               }
            ],
            "header":[  
               {  
                  "show":true,
                  "fontcolor":"#8aa5d1"
               }
            ],
            "labels":[  
               {  
                  "backColor":"#456B99",
                  "fontColor":"#8aa5d1",
                  "fontSize":"12",
                  "labelStyle":"Percent of total"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Donut Chart doesnt have Header property

Answer (score 0):

You have done this correctly, but unfortunately Power BI does not yet support title cardNames for any of their visuals.

I've voted on the [Power BI Ideas page](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/31543114-format-visualization-title-with-report-themes) for this problem. Maybe you would like to as well :)